# NPM let execute ( beginner ..)

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, npm

i installed this tool on my ubuntu machine via npm:

https://github.com/thanhnguyennguyen/trading-indicator

now i should have via:

```
let ticker = await indicators.ticker("binance", symbol, true)
```

but where is the easiest way to get the value? do i have to include it in an html file?

sorry for the beginner question. google is not helping me right now. thanks!

unfortunately, it is not possible via terminal.

Comment: It's not a tool, it's a library. You need to write the application yourself that uses it. We have no idea what kind of tool you want, so we can't help you with that.

Comment: i want to read the rsi value with this library.
https://github.com/thanhnguyennguyen/trading-indicator#stochastic-rsi

do i have to create an html file and include all js. data there?

Comment: **If** you want to display it in a web browser, then yes html is the way to go.